# Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I've read similar questions about this warning in Haskell, but these generally envolve lists and mine doesn't:

```
teste :: Char -> Char -> Int
teste a b
   |ord (toUpper a) < ord (toUpper b) = 1
   |ord (toUpper a) > ord (toUpper b) = 2
   |ord a > ord (toUpper b) = 3
   |ord a < ord (toUpper b) = 4
```

Why the "pattern matches" warning is showing up?

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for `teste': Patterns not matched: _ _
```

Is there something I can do?

Edit: The new function's code:

```
alphabetOrder :: Char -> Char -> Char 
alphabetOrder a b =  case compare (toUpper a) (toUpper b) of LT -> a; GT -> b; EQ -> a
```

Comment: By the way, the calls to `ord` aren't necessary. `ord x < ord y` always has the same value as `x < y` (and similarly for the other comparison operators).

Comment: Your guards do not cover all the possible cases, as others pointed out. Even if they did, the compiler is not smart enough to detect that: after all, the guards could be complex expressions, and the problem is undecidable. GHC pretty much expects that the last guard is `otherwise`, or it will conservatively assume that guards are not exhaustive and warn accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What should the result be when `ord a == ord (toUpper b)`? You haven't specified that, and that's a real possibility.

But then, even if you did specify that, the compiler still wouldn't be able to tell that `>`, `<`, and `==` cover all possible cases. For the compiler, `>`, `<`, and `==` are just some functions, it can't prove that one of them will always return `True`.

So what you really need to do is add a case that will be matched when no other case matches:

```
teste :: Char -> Char -> Int
teste a b
   |ord (toUpper a) < ord (toUpper b) = 1
   |ord (toUpper a) > ord (toUpper b) = 2
   |ord a > ord (toUpper b) = 3
   |ord a < ord (toUpper b) = 4
   |otherwise = 5
```

Comment: Another alternative: the compiler isn't able to tell that `<`, `>`, and `==` cover all possible cases, but it is able to tell that `LT`, `EQ`, and `GT` cover all possible cases. `teste a b = case compare (ord (toUpper a)) (ord (toUpper b)) of LT -> 1; GT -> 2; EQ -> case compare (ord a) (ord (toUpper b)) of LT -> 3; GT -> 4; EQ -> 5`.

Comment: Or the same thing just one case expression, by matching a tuple of both comparisons. `teste a b = case (compare (toUpper a) (toUpper b), compare a (toUpper b)) of (LT, _) -> 1; (GT, _) -> 2; (EQ, LT) -> 3; (EQ, GT) -> 4; (EQ, EQ) -> 5`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I have added suggestions everyone made in this new function: `alphabetOrder :: Char -> Char -> Char
alphabetOrder a b =  case compare (toUpper a) (toUpper b) of LT -> a; GT -> b; EQ -> a` I guess it's way better now. Thanks to everyone.